# Paths alias intellisense of vscode in jsconfig not working

Tags: vuejs3, intellisense, vite, vscode-jsconfig

My source:
https://github.com/powerfulh/Vite

My vscode does not working for import paths intellisense in *.js, *.vue with jsconfig
(*.ts is working with ts config)

My jsconfig:
https://github.com/powerfulh/Vite/blob/master/jsconfig.json

I tried import some module with using paths alias like this
`import someModule from '@/someDir'`

When I typed `import someModule from '@/` in *.vue or *.js, vscode did not show accessable directory

But *.ts is working (My tsconfig: https://github.com/powerfulh/Vite/blob/master/tsconfig.json)

How do I make it work on js(also script tag in *.vue) as well?